# 403 Error When Using a Trying to Upload file with Flask and Vue

Tags: python, node.js, vue.js, flask, cors

I'm trying to reproduce a colleagues small webapp built via flask and node.js. The code runs successfully on Windows but fails on Mac (12.1 OS Mont) with a 403 error as shown below when trying to upload a file via the POST method.[Error Code received in console tab in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIbjU.png)

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

The full app.py file looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS  # Import CORS
import pandas as pd
import json

from filterPlayers import filter_players
from rankPlayers import find_players
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)  # Enable CORS for all routes

@app.route('/api/nothing', methods=['POST'])
def do_nothing():
    try:
        data_received = request.files['file']
        
        # Do something with the received data
        # print("Received data:", data_received)

        # You can send a response back to the frontend if needed
        response_data = {'message': 'Data received successfully'}
        return jsonify(response_data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return jsonify({'error': 'Internal Server Error'}), 500

@app.route('/api/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    try:
        # Get the uploaded file from the request
        uploaded_file = request.files['file']
        position = request.form.get('position')
        minutes = request.form.get('minutes')
        minAge = request.form.get('minAge')
        maxAge = request.form.get('maxAge')
        if minAge == 'null' or minAge == '' and minAge is not None: 
            minAge = 0
        else:
            minAge = int(minAge) 
        if maxAge == 'null' or maxAge == '' and maxAge is not None:
            maxAge = 99
        else:
            maxAge= int(maxAge)
        if position == 'null':
            position = 'Forward'
        # Read the Excel file into a Pandas DataFrame
        df = pd.read_excel(uploaded_file)
        # print(df['Minutes played'].max())
        # print(df['Minutes played'].max()*int(minutes)/100)
        minutes_played = df['Minutes played'].max()*int(minutes)/100
        # zscores = get_zscores(df)
        rankedPlayers = find_players(position, df, minutes_played, minAge, maxAge)

        # Your logic to process the DataFrame goes here
        json_data = rankedPlayers.to_json(orient='records')

        return jsonify(json_data)
    except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
            return jsonify({'error': 'Internal Server Error'}), 500
    
@app.route('/api/filter', methods=['POST'])
def filter():
    try:
        # Get the uploaded file from the request
        uploaded_file = request.files['file']
        position = request.form.get('position')
        minutes = request.form.get('minutes')
        minAge = request.form.get('minAge')
        maxAge = request.form.get('maxAge')
        def_form = request.form.get('def')
        mid_form = request.form.get('mid')
        fwd_form = request.form.get('fwd')
        gk_form = request.form.get('gk')
        extra_form = request.form.get('extra')
        submit = request.form.get('submit')
        def_json = 0
        mid_json = 0
        fwd_json = 0
        gk_json = 0
        extra_json = 0
        if submit is not None:
            def_json = json.loads(def_form)
            mid_json = json.loads(mid_form)
            fwd_json = json.loads(fwd_form)
            gk_json = json.loads(gk_form)
            extra_json = json.loads(extra_form)
        print(minAge, maxAge, minutes)
        if minAge is not None and minAge != "null" and minAge != "":
            minAge = int(minAge)
        else:
            minAge = 0
        if maxAge is not None and maxAge != "null" and maxAge != "":
            maxAge = int(maxAge)
        else:
            maxAge= 99
        if position == 'null':
            position = 'Forward'
        # Read the Excel file into a Pandas DataFrame
        df = pd.read_excel(uploaded_file)
        # print(df['Minutes played'].max())
        # print(df['Minutes played'].max()*int(minutes)/100)
        if minutes is not None and minutes != "null" and minutes != "":
            minutes_played = df['Minutes played'].max()*int(minutes)/100
        else:
            minutes_played = 0
        filteredPlayers = filter_players(df, position, minutes_played, minAge, maxAge, def_json, mid_json, fwd_json, gk_json, extra_json)
        # rankedPlayers = find_players(position, df, minutes_played, minAge, maxAge)

        # Your logic to process the DataFrame goes here
        json_data = filteredPlayers.to_json(orient='records')

        return jsonify(json_data)
    except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
            return jsonify({'error': 'Internal Server Error'}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I've tried changing the port number on mac to 8000 via

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8000, debug=True)
```

as shown here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72795799/how-to-solve-403-error-with-flask-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com) but it didn't help.

Would be helpful for info in any direction!

Comment: I was facing the same issue recently, it was a CORS error. I have tried different ways to resolve "CORS(app)" By writing this it was not working, So I have enabled CORS with @app.before_request.