# Flask app throws 403 forbiden after refreshing the page

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, cors

My react app starts smoothly on first opening , then after any refresh i start getting 403 forbidden error , which makes my development super slow. any solution will be welcomed !

Backend running on Python Flask following are configs for CORS :

```
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": ["http://localhost:3000","http://127.0.0.1:3000/"]}})
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")
```

[image: Error]

Running on Mac m2

Comment: You have the origin set as port 3000, but your log shows port 5000.

Comment: port 5000 is my backend , the front is running on 3000 @TimRoberts

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue of Mac OSX 12~ that the port 5000 is used for the control center.

How about trying some other port?

##### Reference 1:

[How to solve 403 error with Flask in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72795799/how-to-solve-403-error-with-flask-in-python)

> Mac OSX Monterey (12.x) currently uses ports 5000 and 7000 for its
> Control centre hence the issue.
>
> Try running your app from port other than 5000 and 7000
>
> use this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8000, debug=True)
```

> and then run your flask file, eg: app.py
>
> python app.py
>
> You can also run using the flask command line interface using this command provided you have set the environment variable necessary for flask CLI.
>
> flask run --port 8000
>
> You can also turn off AirPlay Receiver in the Sharing via System Preference.
>
> Related discussion here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332
>
> Update(November 2022):
>
> Mac OSX Ventura(13.x) still has this problem and is fixed with the change in default port as mentioned above.

##### Reference 2:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693768

> I figured this out. Monterrey has Airplay Receiver listening on Port 5000. > You can disable it in System Preferences => Sharing => AirPlay Receiver.
>
> Here is more info.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35415727)

Comment: Thank you @wdetac. I added the essential parts of the links.